# Searching AdminDirectory in GAS not working with quote in name

Tags: google-apps-script

I am searching Google Apps Script like this:

```
var list = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: MYDOMAIN,
    maxResults: 100,
    query: searchQuery,
    viewType: 'domain_public',
    projection: 'full'
}).users;
```

It works fine until I try to search for a name like O'Leary.  I did quote the quote so that my searchQuery looks like this:

```
 familyName:O\'Leary*
```

I also tried enclosing it in quotes, which gave an error.  This [doc](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users) indicates that it should work, unless I am reading it wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When you say you tried it in quotes, you mean:  `familyName:'O\'Leary*'`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ug, I had the * outside the quotes.  Thanks for making me look, @Bardy.